# imshow segmentation fault with (1,2**16) array

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

An empty or random filled array with the dimension `(x,2**16)` crashes with a segmentation fault after `plt.show()` is called.
when the array is transposed it does not crash.
when the array is just one index smaller or greater it does not crash either.
It also does not crash when the option `interpolation='none'` is removed from the command

'not working' example

```
a = np.zeros((1,2**16))
plt.imshow(a,interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

**versions**:

**python**:  2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) [GCC 6.3.0 20170118]

**matplotlib**:  1.5.1

**numpy**:  1.11.1

Since it crashes with a seg-fault it is probably a bug but maybe somebody has an idea.

thanks in advance

Comment: what os? virtual machine?

Comment: The code works fine for me with matplotlib 2.0.2, numpy 1.13 and python 2.7.10. Maybe you shouldn't try to set any interpolation on an image with only one pixel in one of the dimensions.

Comment: I found these questions that sound similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764895/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-using-matplotlib-on-ubuntu-mate-16-04 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11487

Comment: Sorry OS is Debian Stretch 64 bit on a lenovo x220. The problem occurs with more than one pixel in x dimension aswell